# Xtend creating variable of explicit type

Tags: variables, xtend

I want to go over list of objects of type Expression and pick last of them, however I am unable to do this, because Xtend has implicit type inference.

```
var myexp= null
for (statement : statements) {
  if (statement instanceof something)
      myexp=statement
}
```

if i initialize myexp on null, it does not work (conflicting types), if create variable without assignment, it is error too... Is there a way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xtend also allows explicit types, and that's what you need here:

```
var Something myexp
for (statement : statements) {
    if (statement instanceof Something)
        myexp = statement
}
```

Or use the Iterable extensions:

```
val myexp = statements.filter(Something).head
```

Comment: I think that you meant filter(Something).last